# How to show actual colour of an image on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

So I am creating a website and have several logos to place in a section, how can I keep their default colour gray and when a user hovers on a logo, it reveals the actual colours of the logo, the logo has several colours so I can't do a simple colour change to a single colour. For eg. the python logo should have both blue and yellow on hover and complete gray without hover.

I know how to change to a single colour only

Comment: wrong approach. Keep the original mask and gray-out the image with a mask. When hovering the image, disable the mask: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/grayscale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `filter: grayscale()` in CSS. `grayscale(1)` will grayout an image will on `:hover` can use `grayscale(0)` to reset the grayout and show the image in color:

```css
img {
max-height: 70vh;
  max-width: 70vw;
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
```

```html
<img src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg">
```

Answer (score -2):

You need two vwersions of your logo: gray and color, an then swap them on hover like

```
this:
div {
    background: url('gray-logo.png');
}
div:hover {
    background: url('color-logo.png');
}
```

Comment: inefficient for bandwidth and storage and accessibility. Images should not be replace by 2 background images (that screen readers can't access)  with twice the load while you could simply use a filter.